# How do i get multiple parameters working with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

```
<Route path="/brand/:id/page=:pageNumber" component={list} value='brand' />
<Route path="/brand/:id/page=:pageNumber/:id" component={detailed} />
```

Having an issue with the above piece of code, when I navigate to 'brand/exampleText/page=1/a38227' it will keep on giving me back the list component rather than the detailed, has anyone ever encountered this? or am i going about this in the completely wrong way?

If you need anymore information to help me let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Place Your details Route over the list route

```
<Route path="/brand/:id/page=:pageNumber/:id" component={detailed} />
<Route path="/brand/:id/page=:pageNumber" component={list} value='brand' />
```

When you hit with your url it matches with first route and not even bother to look the second one